# Let E be a non-empty set. Let's consider the inclusion relation over P(E) : (∀x, y ∈ P(E))(X ≤ Y ⇔ X ⊂ Y ). Show that it is an order relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation, equivalence-relations

Let E be a non-empty set. Let's consider the inclusion relation over P(E): (∀x, y ∈ P(E))(X ≤ Y ⇔ X ⊂ Y )

(a) Show that it is an order relation.
(b) Show that it is total if, and only if,
E = {a}

I know that I have to prove that it is reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive, but how do I do that? And how do I show that it is total when E = {a}?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: x ≤ x therefore it is reflexive, x ≤ y and y ≤ x so x = y then it is antisymmetric and if x ≤ y and y ≤ z then x ≤ z then it is transitive but idk if that's right

Comment: Please do not use Unicode characters for math symbols. Take a look at the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to see how to typeset the math in your question. Also, the comment in which you showed your attempt should not be a comment but instead added to the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \leq y$ and $y \leq z$ then $x \subseteq y$ and $y \subseteq z$. That is, every member in $x$ is a member of $y$. But every member of $y$ is also a member of $z$, hence every member of $x$ is a member of $z$, and so $x \leq z$ means this relation is transitive. Of course, it is reflexive since every set is a subset of itself. It is antisymmetric by the Axiom of Extensionality.

Now, suppose the relation is total. That is, for any members $x$ and $y$ of $E$, either $x \leq y$ or $y \leq x$. If $E$ is not of the form $\{a\}$ then there exists distinct elements $a, b \in E$ since $E$ is non-empty and then neither $\{a\} \leq \{b\}$ nor $\{b\} \leq \{a\}$, a contradiction. So $E$ is a singleton. Likewise, if $E$ is a singleton then trivially $P(E)$ is linearly ordered as $\varnothing \leq \{a\}$.